How to remove optional flags on tuple elements up to and including an index
I'd like to write a utility type that takes a numeric index N and a tuple type T and produces another tuple type of the same length as T where the initial elements up to and including the one at index N are made non-optional.  This should work for regular finite-length tuples, as well as tuples that end in a rest element:
So:
type RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<N extends number, T extends any[]> = ???

type Test1 = RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<1, [a: '1', b?: '2', c?: '3']>
// [a: '1', b: '2', c?: '3'];
// elements at indices 0 and 1 are both required, element 2 is unchanged

type Test2 = RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<1, [a: 1, b?: 2, c?: 3, ...d: 4[]]> 
// [a: 1, b: 2, c?: 3, ...d: 4[]]
// elements at indices 0 and 1 are both required, elements 2 and beyond are unchanged

Is there a way to achieve this?  Note that we need to ensure undefined is removed from type when we require the item, but that undefined is not removed from items that are already required:
type Test3 = RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<1, 
   [a: '1' | undefined, '2' | undefined, '3' | undefined]>;
// [a: "1" | undefined, "2" | undefined, "3" | undefined]

It is also desired that tuple labels be preserved where possible.

Is 2 a 1-based index for some reason? Or the value of the array element? Maybe you could [edit] to put non-numeric elements in your example array and make sure you are clear about array indices being 0-based?

(see prev comment and pls make requested edits) How much do you care about tuple labels being preserved? Trying to do that makes things even clunkier. This playground link shows a possible implementation but I imagine lots of possible edge cases, so you'd need to test it thoroughly before giving it a . If it does meet your needs, let me know and I'll write an answer explaining. If not, please [edit] to make sure you show important use cases where my suggestion fails.

thanks @jcalz I've edited my post - i still have an edge case if a type is undefined ? If you see other edge cases please let me know

• Hmm I wasn’t imagining you’d put my suggestion code in your question, just that you’d show a use case. Could you please edit to not include my suggestion? It belongs in an answer if anywhere. • How do you plan to deal with undefined in the case that the original type was not optional? Do you want [1 | undefined, (2 | undefined)?] to become [1, 2] or [1, 2 | undefined]? I'm just making sure this is something you need the utility type to handle, as opposed to just using --exactOptionalPropertyTypes

Pls see prev comment and make requested edit. • I'm confused about what the undefined issue is doing. Really it seems like you should just list your use cases and then say what you expect to see.  Tuple label preservation in the face of open-ended tuples like [A, B, ...C[]] is probably just too fragile to even try. Personally I'd say if your use cases are likely to have open-ended tuples, to just forget about labels and upvote ms/TS#56093 so that we can programmatically copy labels.

(see prev comments) Like, ugh, oof, I could try something like this approach to handle various edge cases, but this is... well, it's not something that seems scalable. How would you like to proceed here?

@jcalz sorry obout putting the code in question did edit - see edit for what i expect from undefined type

@jcalz here is a playground referencing all edge case non working with undefined

• Note that you haven't mentioned in your question "I need this to work on tuples that end with rest elements", you've just showed a use case that happens to use one while only talking about undefined.  If you didn't need open-ended tuples then the undefined issue wouldn't show up. •  I can also see that your edited code has a typo in it, so you should fix that. •  "after" and "up to" are different. It looks like you've changed what you want at some point with indices. • Could you please [edit] to make it explicit and clear what you want? Otherwise I keep guessing and it's tiring.

(see prev comment and pls make requested edits).  So, right now, this approach is the closest I can get to what I'm guessing you want, with the meaning of the index (as being the last required index, not the first non-required index), and dealing with open-ended tuples while still preserving tuple labels for finite-length tuples. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer (but it will be messy, since the type is messy).  If not, please continue to [edit] in use cases we need to handle.

I thought the edit where clear not sure what can i add. Did you see @jcalz this playground posted earlier that reference all edge cases ?

Playgrounds aren't sufficient for questions, you should make sure everything you care about are also present as plaintext in the question. I did see that playground, but this doesn't address my comment and I'm not sure how to proceed without just repeating myself (I mean, there's a typo in there where you didn't close a tuple properly. Surely that's something you can deal with, right?) Anyway, did you see this playground? Does it handle your edge cases? I can write up an answer and then edit your question myself, if so. Otherwise what am I missing?

oups i indeed did miss you're last playground that answer all use case, thank you very much and sorry for the confusions @jcalz

Writing RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<N, T> so that it deals as you'd like with tuple labels and with rest elements in tuple types and with undefined is fairly complicated.  If I weren't worrying about such edge cases, I'd write
type RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<N extends number, T extends any[], A extends any[] = []> =
    T extends [] ? A :
    `${N}` extends keyof A ? [...A, ...T] :
    T extends [(infer F)?, ...infer R] ? RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<N, R, [...A, F]>
    : never;

This is a tail-recursive conditional type which uses an accumulator A to build up the required part of the result.  Note that if T is empty we just give up and return the accumulator, since we've apparently walked off the end of T before reaching the index we care about.
Once A's length is strictly larger than N, we can just concatenate A with the current rest of the tuple T to get the result. The check `${N}` extends keyof A looks for this by only returning true if the string literal corresponding to N is an index of A.  So if N is 2 and "2" is a key of A, then we've reached the desired length. Meaning that [] is too short, [X] is too short, and [X, X] is too short. But [X, X, X] is long enough. This guarantees that the required part has indices up to and including N.
Anyway, the check T extends [(infer F)?, ...infer R] uses conditional type inference to split T into its initial possibly-optional element F and the rest of the tuple R. And then we recurse.
This is the "simple" implementation, and it sort of behaves how you want:
type Test1 = RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<1, [a: '1', b?: '2', c?: '3']>
// type Test1 = ["1", "2", c?: "3" | undefined]
type Test2 = RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<1, [a: 1, b?: 2, c?: 3, ...d: 4[]]>
// type Test2 = [1, 2, c?: 3 | undefined, ...d: 4[]]
type Test3 = RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<1, [a: '1' | undefined, '2' | undefined, '3' | undefined]>
// type Test3 = ["1", "2", "3" | undefined]

Except that tuple labels are never preserved for the required prefix of the tuple, and undefined is always stripped from the elements.  To fix those, we need more complex things.

Here's the implementation that gets me the closest:
type RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<N extends number, T extends any[], A extends any[] = []> =
    T extends [] ? A :
    `${N}` extends keyof A ? [...A, ...T] :
    number extends T['length'] ? (
        T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<N, R, [...A, F]> :
        T extends [(infer F)?, ...infer R] ? RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<N, R, [...A, F]> :
        never
    ) :
    T extends [any?, ...infer R] ? (
        T extends [...infer F, ...R] ?
        RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<N, R, [...A, ...Required<F>]> :
        never
    ) : never;

First, the number extends T['length'] check is to deal with tuples that end in rest elements. Tuple labels cannot be preserved with these, as far as I know. It would be great if we could arbitrarily assign labels, such as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#56093, but we can't. We need various tricks to spread tuples instead of making them from scratch. But open-ended tuples break those tricks. So we avoid them.
Inside the open-ended tuple branch, I add two checks instead of one. First we check if the first element is not optional by matching against [infer F, ...infer R] instead of [(infer F)?, ...infer R].  This will only succeed if the first element is required. In that case, undefined, if present, will be preserved. So [...A, F] will append an (unlabeled) element to the accumulator, preserving undefined if necessary.  Otherwise we fall back to the [(infer F)?, ...infer R] check, which will succeed whether or not the first element is optional. But we know we'll only get here if it's optional, so F will not have undefined in it, and [...A, F] will append an (unlabeled) element to the accumulator, stripping off undefined.
In the finite-length tuple branch, we use a trick to preserve tuple labels. The pair of checks T extends [any?, ...infer R] ? T extends [...infer F, ...R] works to first grab every element after the first, and then we spread the first element into F. So F is expected to be a one-element tuple type. This tuple will still have the label from T's first element. It will also be either optional or required.  So when we recurse, we need to use Required on it to remove the optional modifier if present (which naturally does what you want with undefined).  Hence [...A, ...Required<F>].
Now we can look at those tests again:
type Test1 = RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<1, [a: '1', b?: '2', c?: '3']>
// type Test1 = [a: "1", b: "2", c?: "3" | undefined]
type Test2 = RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<1, [a: 1, b?: 2, c?: 3, ...d: 4[]]>
// type Test2 = [1, 2, c?: 3 | undefined, ...d: 4[]]
type Test3 = RequiredTupleUpToAndIncluding<1, [a: '1' | undefined, '2' | undefined, '3' | undefined]>
// type Test3 = [a: "1" | undefined, "2" | undefined, "3" | undefined]

Looks reasonable. Tuple labels are now preserved for Test1 and Test3. They are still gone in Test2, but there's nothing I can do about that. Furthermore undefined is only removed when the element was optional, so Test3 is the expected type.

There you go. Note that there are almost certainly other weird edge cases lurking. I don't know what happens if you use unions for N or T, or what happens if you use tuples with leading or middle rest elements, or any other things that go bump in the night.  I've only focused on the use cases presented in the question. Future readers might find they need to significantly refactor the code for it to work as they desire, or worse, it might turn out to be impossible. This is a general caveat with complicated recursive conditional types. They are inherently fragile, so you need to subject them to a test suite before you even think about using them in any sort of production code.
Playground link to code

It covers enought use case for what i need it to
Thank you very much

I tried your solution and found a hack, I decided to share it here
type Tail<T extends any[]> =
    T extends [] ? [] :
    T extends [any?, ...infer Tail] ? Tail : never

type Head<T extends any[]> = number extends T['length']
    ? [T[0]]
    : T extends [...infer Head, ...Tail<T>] ? Head : []

type RequiredTupleBefore<N extends number, T extends any[], A extends any[] = []> =
    A['length'] extends N ? [...A, ...T] :
    T extends [] ? [...A, ...T] :
    RequiredTupleBefore<N, Tail<T>, [...A, ...Required<Head<T>>]>

type test = RequiredTupleBefore<1, [a: 1, b?: 2, c?: 3]> 
//     ^?

type RemoveNullable<T extends any[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[K]>
}

// @ts-expect-error
type test3 = RemoveNullable<RequiredTupleBefore<1, [a: 1, b?: 2, c?: 3, d: 4]>>
//     ^?
//      

const a:test3=[1,2,3,4] // ok, no error
const b:test3=[1,undefined,undefined,undefined] // ok, error


There is an error but I suppress it, it is weird but it works
playground

I do not see what you've added ??? and [a: 1, b?: 2, c?: 3, d: 4] is not legal (required items after optional ones

that is the point, the illegal d:4 is the reason it works

But since it's illegal that hack wont be usable.

it can be used if you suppress the error.
this is not intended as answer, i write it because i want to take a look at it later
